# enum option "new" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I am trying to create an enum on my model and I would like one of the states to be "new"

e.g.

```
enum status: { stale: 0, new: 1, converted: 2 }
```

It seems rails rejects this with the following error.

```
You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "Lead", but this will generate a class method "new", which is already defined by Active Record.
```

I understand why this is happening, but I was wondering if there is no way to get around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error clearly states that you cannot have an enum with `new` key as it will conflict with an existing `ActiveRecord` method. There is no way out of this.

This issue is not new and it has been discussed before.

I would recommend you to read

**[enum: Option not to generate "dangerous" class methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14160)**

As per `Godfrey Chan`, Collaborator of Rails:

> In this case, if you want to use enum, you are probably better off
> renaming your label to something else. This is not unique to enums – a
> lot of Active Record features generates methods for you and usually
> there aren't ways to opt-out of those generated methods.
>
> Gonna give this one a close for now....

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs due to [reserved words in Rails](https://gist.github.com/antonfefilov/14b1eaf740b02cba8be0#file-reserved-words-for-rails-L109). To solve this issue, you can use two options:

1. Rename the attribute `status` to another non reserved word. E.g.: `kind`
2. Or just add the `_prefix: :status` in the enum. E.g: `enum status: { stale: 0, new: 1, converted: 2 }, _prefix: :status`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by leaving **config / environments / production.rb** as default and everything returned to normal without errors